# Remove foreign key association to prevent cascade deletion sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, cascade

I have a table Products and a table Sales. In my Products table I have

```
  Products.associate = function (models) {
    Products.hasMany(models.Sales, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
  };
```

I've realised that if I delete a product I will delete all the rows in sales which sell this product... I don't want to do that, as I don't want to lose my history. How do I either (i) prevent the delete from cascading now my change is live in production or (ii) how do I remove the relationship entirely.

In both cases, what is the API(s) I should by calling from my migration file?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to lose your history you cannot delete the product either. If you do you have sales with a product. Neither can you remove the relationship either because then you can have sales for a product that does not, nor perhaps has not ever existed. The solution is to logically delete the product. Do this by adding a column to the products table that indicates this is an active or deleted product. Then do not allow sales for deleted products.

Comment: i don't like the logical delete. let me ask my questions another way. can I change the foreign key on table Sales into a new field - perhaps I  copy the foriegn key value as a string into a new field, and then remove the foreign key relationship?